# How do I Convert nginx to Apache rewrites

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

My local machine is **Apache** and this is the redirect scheme on **nginx**. How do I write this using RewriteRules?

---

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/$ /index.php?url=home;
  }
}

location /admin {
  rewrite ^/admin$ /access.php;
  rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /access.php?page=$1;
}

location /s {
  rewrite ^/s/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$ index.php?url=share&share=$1;
}

location /media {
  rewrite ^/media/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$ index.php?url=home&media=$1;
}

location /lang {
  rewrite ^/lang/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$ index.php?url=lang&lang=$1;
}

location /page {
  rewrite ^/page/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$ index.php?url=page&page=$1;
}

location /articles {
  rewrite ^/articles(\/|)$ index.php?url=articles;
  rewrite ^/articles/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$ index.php?url=articles&id=$1;
  rewrite ^/articles/([^\/]+)/post/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$ index.php?url=articles&id=$1&post=$2;
}
```

Comment: Apache's [RewriteRule directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) has an almost identical syntax as nginx's **rewrite**. So what part of **nginx** config do you need help translating?

Comment: I need to change all the rules above. please give me a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to activate **mod_rewrite** in your Apache config and add to your virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/$" "/index.php?url=home" [L]
RewriteRule "^/admin$" "/access.php" [L]
RewriteRule "^/admin/(.*)$" "/access.php?page=$1" [L]
RewriteRule "^/s/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$" "index.php?url=share&share=$1" [L]
RewriteRule "^/media/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$" "index.php?url=home&media=$1" [L]
RewriteRule "^/lang/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$" "index.php?url=lang&lang=$1" [L]
RewriteRule "^/page/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$" "index.php?url=page&page=$1" [L]
RewriteRule "^/articles(\/|)$" "index.php?url=articles" [L]
RewriteRule "^/articles/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$" "index.php?url=articles&id=$1" [L]
RewriteRule "^/articles/([^\/]+)/post/([^\/]+)(\/|)?$" "index.php?url=articles&id=$1&post=$2" [L]
```

The directives are almost identical to **nginx** directives and described in [mod_rewrite manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: thanks :) very best. worked