# Nginx rewrite to Apache rewriterule for path

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, apache-2.4

I have a landing page and a text box. They enter some input into the text box and get taken to /search, which I want to load search_res.html. My file structure is:

```
/var/www/html
    index.html
    search_res.html
```

I've got it working on Nginx, but I must migrate to Apache. I can't seem to get the following Nginx code work on an Apache webserver:

```
location /search {
    rewrite ^/search$ /search_res.html; 
}
```

I have reviewed [How do I Convert nginx to Apache rewrites](https://serverfault.com/questions/994755/how-do-i-convert-nginx-to-apache-rewrites), and have added:

`RewriteRule ^/search$ "search_res.html" [R=302,NC,L]` but I am still seeing a 404 error.
. Any ideas how this can be done?

The virtualhost config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:10002>


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName ${SERVER_ENV}

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "certs/mysubdomain.com.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "certs/private.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "certs/server.csr"


<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>      

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine   On 
    RewriteRule "^search$" "/search_res.html" [NC,L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Convert nginx to Apache rewrites](https://serverfault.com/questions/994755/how-do-i-convert-nginx-to-apache-rewrites)

Comment: I keep getting The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **nginx** configuration you used an internal rewrite, instead of a `302` redirect, so I would guess you want something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/search$" "/search_res.html" [NC,L]
```

inside the `<VirtualHost>` tags.

Comment: How can I confirm that it is going here? I still get a 404 not found

Comment: Did you set up `DocumentRoot` to the same value as the `root` directive in **nginx**. Can you add your `<VirtualHost>` config to the question?

Comment: I've added it, let me know if there's something out of place

Comment: Your rewrite rule is in the `<Directory>` context, so `http://example.com/search` is transformed into `search` (without leading slash) before the comparison. Either replace `^/search$` with `^search$` or move the rules inside the `<VirtualHost>` tag.

Comment: I have done both and still see 404..what can be causing this?

Comment: You can check apache's logs.