# How do I Convert nginx to Apache rewrites?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

My local machine is Apache2.4 and this is the redirect scheme on nginx. How do I write this using RewriteRules?

```
location / {
 if (!-e $request_filename) {
   rewrite ^/(.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+).html$ /index.php?mod=$1 last;
 }
 rewrite ^/pay/(.*)$ /pay.php?s=$1 last;
}
location ^~ /plugins {
  deny all;
}
location ^~ /includes {
  deny all;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! What have you tried so far?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
  location / {
 if (!-e $request_filename) {
   rewrite ^/(.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+).html$ /index.php?mod=$1 last;
 }
 RewriteRule ^pay/(.*)$ pay.php?s=$1
}
location ^~ /plugins {
  deny all;
}
location ^~ /includes {
  deny all;
}` #try this first

Comment: I tried this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+).html$ index.php?mod=$1
RewriteRule ^pay/(.*)$ pay.php?s=$1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Convert nginx to Apache rewrites](https://serverfault.com/questions/994755/how-do-i-convert-nginx-to-apache-rewrites)

Comment: You don't still have the original Apache rewrite rules that these were converted from?